# Problem parsing values of PostgreSQL TIMESTAMP type

Tags: go

In PostgreSQL, I have table called `surveys`.

```
CREATE TABLE SURVEYS(
  SURVEY_ID UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  SURVEY_NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  SURVEY_DESCRIPTION TEXT,
  START_PERIOD TIMESTAMP,
  END_PERIOD TIMESTAMP
);
```

As you can see only `SURVEY_ID` and `SURVEY_NAME` columns are `NOT NULL`.

In Go, I want to create new entry in that table by `POST` request. I send JSON object like this:

```
{
    "survey_name": "NAME",
    "survey_description": "DESCRIPTION",
    "start_period": "2019-01-01 00:00:00",
    "end_period": "2019-02-28 23:59:59"
}
```

Unfortunatly it raise strange **ERROR**:

```
parsing time ""2019-01-01 00:00:00"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse " 00:00:00"" as "T"
```

Where I make mistake and how to fix my problem?

**models/surveys.go:**

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "time"
)

type NullTime struct {
    time.Time
    Valid bool
}

type Survey struct {
    ID int `json:"survey_id"`
    Name string `json:"survey_name"`
    Description sql.NullString `json:"survey_description"`
    StartPeriod NullTime `json:"start_period"`
    EndPeriod NullTime `json:"end_period"`
}
```

**controllers/surveys.go:**

```
var CreateSurvey = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    // Initialize variables.
    survey := models.Survey{}
    var err error

    // The decoder introduces its own buffering and may read data from argument beyond the JSON values requested.
    err = json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&survey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        utils.ResponseWithError(responseWriter, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer request.Body.Close()

    // Execute INSERT SQL statement.
    _, err = database.DB.Exec("INSERT INTO surveys (survey_name, survey_description, start_period, end_period) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4);", survey.Name, survey.Description, survey.StartPeriod, survey.EndPeriod)

    // Shape the response depending on the result of the previous command.
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        utils.ResponseWithError(responseWriter, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    utils.ResponseWithSuccess(responseWriter, http.StatusCreated, "The new entry successfully created.")
}
```

Comment: [time.Time's UnmarshalJSON](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON) uses [RFC3339](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#RFC3339) format to parse the timestamp string, so you need to change the format of the timestamps that you're sending in the json accordingly, or you need to implement your own `UnmarshalJSON` on your `NullTime` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error already says what is wrong:

> parsing time ""2019-01-01 00:00:00"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse " 00:00:00"" as "T"

You are passing `"2019-01-01 00:00:00"` while it expects a different time format, namely [RFC3339](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#RFC3339) ([UnmarshalJSON's default](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON)).

To solve this, you either want to pass the time in the expected format `"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z00:00"` or define your own type `CustomTime` like this:

```golang
const timeFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

type CustomTime time.Time

func (ct *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    newTime, err := time.Parse(timeFormat, strings.Trim(string(data), "\""))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *ct = CustomTime(newTime)
    return nil
}

func (ct *CustomTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%q", time.Time(*ct).Format(timeFormat))), nil
}
```

Careful, you might also need to implement the `Valuer` and the `Scanner` interfaces for the time to be parsed in and out of the database, something like the following:

```golang
func (ct CustomTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return time.Time(ct), nil
}

func (ct *CustomTime) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if val, ok := src.(time.Time); ok {
        *ct = CustomTime(val)
    } else {
        return errors.New("time Scanner passed a non-time object")
    }

    return nil
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RAEGhJ-2sKW) example.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I am little bit confused. Where exactly I need to integrate your example code in my code?!

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek you can add it in your project tree right next to `models/surveys.go` if you don't use it anywhere else. You will need to adjust the type `CustomTime` to your type `NullTime`.

Comment: In fact `start_period` and `end_period` values are inside `request.Body`. I use it in `controllers/surveys.go` file as you can see. Sow as I understand I need to call this functions somehow in handler, right? Why they don't have names?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek You don't have to call any functions. These are implementation of interfaces for this `CustomTime`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed example. Right now I have error: `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Survey.survey_description of type sql.NullString`. I changed `Description sql.NullString` to `Description string`. After that I have other error: `sql: converting argument $3 type: unsupported type models.NullTime, a struct`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Also why `timeFormat` variable has such value `2006-01-02 15:04:05`?

Comment: Inside `controllers/surveys.go` file I need remove `NewDecoder` to `Unmarshal`, right?

Comment: You don't need to remove anything. Just copy the `const timeFormat`, `type CustomTime` and both methods somewhere in your files. Then, replace `time.Time` inside `NullTime` with `CustomTime`. This is all you need to do.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek to be able to save/retrieve custom struct types like your `NullTime` you need to have them implement the [Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) and [Valuer](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interfaces. As an example just look at the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) documentation, there you'll find multiple custom `NullXxx` struct types, including [`NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString), and they all implement the two interfaces. You need to do that too to fix the `sql: unsupported type` error.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek *"why timeFormat variable has such value 2006-01-02 15:04:05?"* It's referred to as the "reference time". The reference time is used by the `time` package to parse the layout value, based on which it will then [`Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse)/[`Format`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) the `time.Time` values. If you go to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) and search (CTRL+F) for "reference time" you'll find enough information to help you better understand it.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? As you can see `start_period` and `end_period` columns are not nessary. If I send empty values for that colomns in database I see such value: `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. Why it happens?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek it depends on how you implemented the `Value() (driver.Value, error)` method.

Comment: Well, I use this: `func (ct CustomTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {return time.Time(ct), nil}`

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek for example take a look at how [`NullString`](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=5290:5340#L194) does it, if it's not valid it returns `nil` which gets saved as `NULL` in the db. So you have to check if your CustomTime is valid, if it is not return `nil`, if it is return what you're returning now.

Comment: I don't know why but I can't use `.Valid` method. It seems like I can use it only for string type. I notice that `func (ct CustomTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {fmt.Println(ct)}` show in console `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. It seems like this value can in other place.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Valid is not part of the CustomTime as suggested by Abdullah, it was a field declared on your original type `NullTime`, and I recommend you stick to that approach. Use all of abdulla's suggestions but instead of CustomTime use NullTime, i.e. implement those methods on NullTime and drop CustomTime altogether. And just to clarify, the naming is not the problem here, the structure of the type is, so if you want to call it CustomTime go ahead, just change it to the correct structure. Example: https://play.golang.com/p/JU7xUuQTCO1