# How can I format date and time in golang to use it in neo4j query?

Tags: go, neo4j, date-formatting

I'm developing a website to learn how to use golang packages:

- `github.com/gin-gonic/gin`, and
- `github.com/johnnadratowski/golang-neo4j-bolt-driver`.

I have a `User` struct like that

```
type User struct {
    Id          int16     `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Username    string    `json:"username" db:"username"`
    Email       string    `json:"email" db:"email"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"
}
```

and i want to create a node in neo4j with all this information

```
func test(u User) {
    m := structs.Map(u)

    app.Neo.ExecNeo("CREATE (n:NODE {Id: {Id}, Username: {Username}, "+
        "Email: {Email}, CreatedAt: {CreatedAt}})", m)
}
```

because of the format of the date "0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"
neo4j does't accept the query (everything work if i remove the 
`CreatedAt`).

So, I wanted to know how i can format it, are there any tips? or do i have to write my own function?

Comment: time.Format lets you format time.Time the way you need.

Comment: Which format does `neo4j` accept? You can use your own time type and implement the `UnmarshalJSON` and `MarshalJSON` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921922/5198756)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I'have found the solution I needed to format the date time from 
`"0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"` to `"0001-01-01T00:00:00+0000"`.

ex : 
`CREATE (n:NODE {Id: 2, Username: "Toto", Email: "Toto@titi.com", 
CreateAt:'0001-01-01T00:00:00'})`